# access data from iron-router in rendered function

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to access data passed from iron router in the javascript function

router.js

```
this.route('editOrganization', {
    path: '/editOrganization',
    waitOn: function() {
      return [
        Meteor.subscribe('organization', this.userId)
      ];
    },
    data: function() {
        return Organizations.findOne();
    }
});
```

now if I wanted to access a property of organization in html (editCompany.html) I can do the following

```
{{name}}
```

but how do I access that same property in the js file

```
Template.editOrganization.rendered = function() {
    //how do I access name?
}
```

UPDATE:
so if I click a link to edit organization I can get the value via

```
this.data.name
```

However, if I reload the page (same url) it throws an error saying data is null.

Comment: Should it be Template.editOrganization.rendered?

Comment: yea sorry, just wrote it out quickly, but not the problem in code (changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is accessible through the rendered function context.

```
Template.editOrganization.rendered = function() {
    var name = this.data && this.data.name;
};
```

This is confusing for many people but you need to configure the router to actually wait for the subscriptions you returned with waitOn.

```
Router.onBeforeAction('loading')
```

You can read the author's explanation here:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/554#issuecomment-39002306

Comment: hmm so I get the value if I click through the link to edit organization, but if I reload, it throws error saying data is null

Comment: @Saad updated to include global `onBeforeAction` and check that `this.data` is defined.